# Add Event Listener not working

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that i never had before.

I wanna call a function when a mobile device change is orientation, so i'm using "onorientationchange" and to be sure it's triggered, i also use "onresize".

The problem is that the even don't work on the page for a mysterious reason :

if i do

```
document.body.addEventListener("resize",function(){console.log("here")};
```

it doesn't work, I so created a custom  version of AddEventListener :

```
function addNewEvent(elementDOM, evenement, fonction){
        var refEvent = null;
        if(elementDOM)
        {
        elementDOM["on"+evenement] = fonction;
            if (elementDOM.attachEvent)
            {
                refEvent =function() {
                    return fonction.call(elementDOM,window.event);
                };
                elementDOM.attachEvent ('on'+evenement,refEvent);
            }
            else if (elementDOM.addEventListener)
            {
                refEvent = fonction;
                elementDOM.addEventListener (evenement,refEvent,false);
            }
            else
            {
                elementDOM["on"+evenement] = fonction;
            }
        }
        return refEvent;
    },
```

And even this one don't work...

BUT this works :

```
document.body.onresize = function(){console.log("here")};
```

it's a normal webpage, i don't get why it doesn't work.

Can you help? :x

Comment: "want to", not "wanna"

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to write proper sentences and use correct capitalization and spelling. It "sounds" like you're a native English speaker, but even if you weren't, I can't imagine anyone getting to that level of competence without knowing basic things like that "I" is always capitalized, as is "I'm", sentences start with a capital, they end with puncutation, etc., etc.

Comment: Yes sorry guys, I rushed a bit much. sry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`resize` events fire on the `window` object, not the `body` element.

You're listening for it in the wrong place.

```
window.addEventListener("resize",function(e){console.log("here", e.target)};
```

Comment: but why document.body.onresize works in this case? :x

Anyway thx, i'm so idiot, that was the answer ^^

Comment: @user3241192 — Legacy weirdness from before they wrote a proper spec and thought about what actually made sense.